# Assembly, loading from disk without INT13 AH02

Tags: debugging, assembly, interrupt, disk, bochs

I'm debugging a 16bit bootloader with Bochs and IDA Pro.

I'm searching the point where the bootloader loads the main program from disk to memory. I have located this code segment in the hard disk and later, into the memory. By this I mean that I know that there is a fragment of code on disk and that I know that it will be loaded later because I see how it is running.

I searched for INT 13 in memory (0xCD13) and I have put a breakpoint on all of this interruptions. First time I reached the breakpoint was because the Bochs BIOS is loading the MBR from disk,
so far everything normal.

I searched again for INT 13, and I have put new breakpoints in new locations. After continuing with the execution, no breakpoint has reached, and the code has been executed.

I have put a Write Watchpoint in the region of memory where the binary is loaded from disk, to know which part of code is loading this. The surprise is that it has been a fragment of the BIOS code (About 0x5B of the Physical memory).

I don't know what's happening here, who is loading the code? And where? I need help.

Comment: If it's obfuscated code, it's certainly possible to invoke the int 13 handler other than using the actual `int` instruction. You should see the caller in the backtrace though so look though the call stack.

Comment: ANy chance you can make this bootloader available to look at?

Comment: An observation. You want to look for int 0x13 in memory that is byte 0xcd, 0x13. As a word that would be 0x13cd

Comment: I cannot share the bootloader, but Jester is right, the code is loaded dinamically, I can not set the breakpoints through executions

Comment: If the code in the bootloader is using the BIOS and let us say they aren't using `int 13h` directly but are using the BIOS nonetheless - why not set a breakpoint in the BIOS area where the Int 13h handler begins. You can find that location by looking at the interrupt table that starts at 0x0000:0x0000 in memory. Int 13h is at 0x0000:0x004C (0x4c/4=0x13). At that address is the offset (16-bit WORD) of the Int 13h vector and after that is the segment (also a WORD). Take those values and set a break point there?

Comment: Hi @Michael Petch, I'm trying to do what you say, but it seems that doesn't work :(